# Is it possible to parallax an img tag rather than background image in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I've come across a number of parallaxing tutorials (this one in particular I'm looking at now: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/); however, they all seem to involve a background image in a `<div>` that's fixed. Is is possible to achieve a similar parallax effect if my image is in a `<img>` tag?

Comment: Sure, they're both elements, they both can be positioned with CSS, and they both can be repositioned with JavaScript.

Comment: The reason for background image is that it's CSS-only solution. Other solutions require using Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you use the same attributes then yeah sure it can

An example of this can be seen here:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/