# How to give an html 'img' tag parallax effect, not in background

Tags: html, css, parallax

This might be a common problem and many others would have asked this question too. But I haven't found a solution that works for me.

Is it possible to give parallax effect in html 'img' tag rather that a css background? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to parallax an img tag rather than background image in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392988/is-it-possible-to-parallax-an-img-tag-rather-than-background-image-in-a-div)